# Error with ReadAsMultipartAsync and MultiPartFormDataStreamProvider

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, async-await, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to upload a file asynchronously to my web server ( ASP.NET MVC). Specifically to my web api endpoint. I followed several tutorials but I keep getting an error of null parameters.

It happens when I subclass `MultipartFormDataStreamProvider`. The method `GetLocalFileName`, gets called first correctly, with the proper `HttpContentHeaders`, but then gets called a second time with `null` headers.

The file is successfully saved with the filename I set, but as I get an exception, I am not able to know what's the name generated.

However if I just use the base `MultipartFormDataStreamProvider` class, the file is saved perfectly, with no errors, but I can't control the filename in this case.

This is the api method:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<FilesUploadResult> Save()
    {
        // Check if the request contains multipart/form-data.
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            var ret = new FilesUploadResult(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType, null);
            ret.Message = "Unsupported Media Type. Request must contain multipart/form-data form.";
            return ret;
        }

        var path = UploadsFolderPath;

        // to-do: this works but for some reason makes a call with empty headers.
        var provider = new SimpleMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(path);

        // this provider saves the file with an arbritrary name
        //var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(path);

        try
        {
            // Read the form data.
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider as MultipartFormDataStreamProvider);

            var files = from f in provider.FileData
                        let info = new FileInfo(f.LocalFileName)
                        select new FileUploadDescription(info.Name, path + "\\" + info.Name, info.Length, HttpStatusCode.Created);

            var ret = new FilesUploadResult(HttpStatusCode.OK, files);
            return ret;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var ret = new FilesUploadResult(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, null);
            ret.Message = ex.Message;
            return ret;
        }
    }
```

This is the code for my `SimpleMultipartFormDataStreamProvider`:

```
public class SimpleMultipartFormDataStreamProvider : MultipartFormDataStreamProvider
{
    public SimpleMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(string path) : base(path) { }

    public override string GetLocalFileName(HttpContentHeaders headers)
    {

        // make sure the headers are valid
        if (headers == null)
        {

            throw new ArgumentNullException("headers");
        }

        // filename
        var filename = CleanString(headers.ContentDisposition.FileName); ;

        // create the local file name
        var localFileName = string.Format("_{0}_{1}", GetRandomName(), filename);

        //this is here because Chrome submits files in quotation marks which get treated as part of the filename and get escaped
        return localFileName.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
    }

    private string GetRandomName()
    {
        return GuidHelper.ShortUniqueId(16);
    }

    private static string CleanString(string str)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
            return string.Empty;

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (char c in str)
        {
            if ((c >= '0' && c <= '9') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || c == '.' || c == '_')
            {
                sb.Append(c);
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Can anybody tell me why I am getting the `GetLocalFileName` called twice and the 2nd time with empty headers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out by myself.

The issue was that the class I implemented to subclass the `MultipartDataStreamProvider` was in a different project.

That project had references to .Net .Http assemblies that were different to the ones currently in the Web Api project.

Only thing I did was to move that CustomMultipartDataStreamProvider class to the same project, and everything worked perfectly.

Comment: This was the problem for me. Had me pulling my hair out for an afternoon. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Even i had encountered such behavior in MVC4 it submits 2 files one of which is empty, so better would be to have a check whether the file has any content and then proceed with saving the file.
There can be multiple approaches for this:
 One of them would be to get the list of all the files from `Request.Files` (this is an array of strings )

```
      foreach (string fileName in Request.Files)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[fileName];
                //Save file content goes here
                if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                 {
                     //logic to save the content
                 }
             }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @nikitech-kolpe, but I'm not sure exactly what Request object are you referring too. Inside my WebApi controller, my Request object doesn't have any property called Files. Is anything else I might be missing?

Answer (score 2):

[GetLocalFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.net.http.multipartfilestreamprovider.getlocalfilename%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) is called once for each file in the multipart request. If you you send two files in the same request GetLocalFileName will be invoked twice. I think you should check how are you invoking the service and use [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or something similar to see if you really are sending two files. If you send several parts in the same request try to specify the ContentType of each part.

Comment: I'll pay attention to that, but I don't think that's the issue, because when I use the default MultipartFormDataStreamProvider I don not get any errors and it only saves one file.